# c# live stream from Ip Camera and how to send video to HTML5 page?

Tags: c#, html, stream, live

I am able to retrieve frames from the IpCamera in C#. Now I have them in memory stream.
My question is how to send this video data to HTML5 page?

P.S: I have to display video in HTML5 tag img (by using src ).
IpCamera I am using is providing only .net user control.

Comment: What have you tried? One solution would be to have a service running on the server which saves the camera images to disk. The client could then load the image ever second or so.

Comment: I dont want to save the images.. it costs lot of memory.. and delay increases